# how to keep material-ui button active after click?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, jss

I created a top navigation bar to define which content will be displayed in the page. I am using material IU buttons for that. I would like to keep the button active after clicking on it, to highlight that the current page content is linked to the button previously clicked. Is it possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use the "**NavLink**" to set the `activeClassName`. In alternative way, You have to manage the active class based on the window URL.

Comment: Thanks, it worked, but I have to use activeStyle instead of activeClassName and declare the style inline. do you know why? I would like to use activeClassName to put my style in style object so that it is reusable... I am using a Button component, I think the theme is overriding it, like this <Button component={NavLink} activeClassName={classes.active}>